# NullPointerException, While filling the IndexedContainer of vaadin in scala

Tags: java, scala, vaadin7

I am trying to fill the **IndexedContainer** of **Vaadin** in **Scala** with the **java.util.List[POJO]**.

**Problem ? ->** Throwing NullPointerException.

**Where ? ->** Place is Shown in Code snippet with Comment.

**Note ->**  The different thing is, I am using iterator to fill the container. I have 7 objects, The things are going proper for 1 object but throwing exception during the insertion of 2nd object.

I am doing the same thing with other Hierarchical Containers and they are working proper.

**Point :** List is not having any null data item.
output is also given in different snippet with the exception.

```
def getOtherAccessContainer(): IndexedContainer = {
    var container = new IndexedContainer
    container.addContainerProperty("User", classOf[Any], "-")
    container.addContainerProperty("user_id", classOf[Any], "-")
    container.addContainerProperty("User Group", classOf[Any], "-")
    container.addContainerProperty("user_familyid", classOf[Any], "-")
    container.addContainerProperty("Object Type", classOf[Any], "-")
    container.addContainerProperty("Object", classOf[Any], "-")
    container.addContainerProperty("object_id", classOf[Any], "-")
    container.addContainerProperty("Object Group", classOf[Any], "-")
    container.addContainerProperty("object_familyid", classOf[Any], "-")
    container.addContainerProperty("Permission", classOf[Any], "-")

    val access_list = accessor.getGrantedObjectList(accessibleuserlist);
    var iterator = access_list.iterator()

    var iterator2 = access_list.iterator()
    println()
    // Just to show that list of POJO is not having null value.
    while (iterator2.hasNext()) {
      val pojo_obj = iterator2.next()
      println(pojo_obj.username + "---" + pojo_obj.user_id + "---" + pojo_obj.user_familyname + "---" + pojo_obj.user_family_id + "---" + pojo_obj.object_type + "---" + pojo_obj.object_name +
        "---" + pojo_obj.object_id + "---" + pojo_obj.object_familyname + "---" + pojo_obj.object_family_id + "---" + pojo_obj.permission)
    }


    // This loop fills the data in container.
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      val pojo_obj = iterator.next()
      var child: Item = container.addItem()
      if (pojo_obj == null) {
        println("Trouble is here." + pojo_obj.username)
      }
      // Print some properties of POJO to be inserted before the Insertion is occured.     
      println("pojo_obj properties :-) " + pojo_obj.username + "---" + pojo_obj.object_name + "---" + pojo_obj.user_id + "---" + pojo_obj.user_familyname + "---" + pojo_obj.user_family_id)

      child.getItemProperty("User").asInstanceOf[Property[Any]].setValue(pojo_obj.username) // <- This line Throws the NullPointerException during 2nd Iteration.
      child.getItemProperty("user_id").asInstanceOf[Property[Any]].setValue(pojo_obj.user_id)// <- If I omitted the line above, It throws NullPointerException for this line and so on. 
      child.getItemProperty("User Group").asInstanceOf[Property[Any]].setValue(pojo_obj.user_familyname)
      child.getItemProperty("user_familyid").asInstanceOf[Property[Any]].setValue(pojo_obj.user_family_id)
      child.getItemProperty("Object Type").asInstanceOf[Property[Any]].setValue(pojo_obj.object_type)
      child.getItemProperty("Object").asInstanceOf[Property[Any]].setValue(pojo_obj.object_name)
      child.getItemProperty("object_id").asInstanceOf[Property[Any]].setValue(pojo_obj.object_id)
      child.getItemProperty("Object Group").asInstanceOf[Property[Any]].setValue(pojo_obj.object_familyname)
      child.getItemProperty("object_familyid").asInstanceOf[Property[Any]].setValue(pojo_obj.object_family_id)
      child.getItemProperty("Permission").asInstanceOf[Property[Any]].setValue(pojo_obj.permission.toString())

    }
    container
  }
```

**Below is the Output:**

```
parth---4cc19690-e819-11e5-a3a1-c1cf090b354c---Analytics Team---ff81457a-e9cf-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66---sa_table---App_Welcome---bce4bd70-ec34-11e5-bbd6-91bbc2299c26---system---9aa06252-e9c6-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66---1
ravi---d1515310-e9ad-11e5-b18e-c1cf090b354c---Analytics Team---ff81457a-e9cf-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66---sa_table---App_Welcome---bce4bd70-ec34-11e5-bbd6-91bbc2299c26---system---9aa06252-e9c6-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66---1
uttam---dca16200-e462-11e5-90ec-c1cf090b354c---Analytics Team---ff81457a-e9cf-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66---sa_table---App_Welcome---bce4bd70-ec34-11e5-bbd6-91bbc2299c26---system---9aa06252-e9c6-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66---1
parth---4cc19690-e819-11e5-a3a1-c1cf090b354c---parth---4cc19690-e819-11e5-a3a1-c1cf090b354c---sa_table--- cluster_test---19713360-ed94-11e5-bf9e-c1cf090b354c---cluster_test---19713360-ed94-11e5-bf9e-c1cf090b354c---0
parth---4cc19690-e819-11e5-a3a1-c1cf090b354c---Analytics Team---ff81457a-e9cf-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66---sa_table---App_Welcome---bce4bd70-ec34-11e5-bbd6-91bbc2299c26---system---9aa06252-e9c6-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66---1
uttam---dca16200-e462-11e5-90ec-c1cf090b354c---Analytics Team---ff81457a-e9cf-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66---sa_table---App_Welcome---bce4bd70-ec34-11e5-bbd6-91bbc2299c26---system---9aa06252-e9c6-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66---1
ravi---d1515310-e9ad-11e5-b18e-c1cf090b354c---Analytics Team---ff81457a-e9cf-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66---sa_table---App_Welcome---bce4bd70-ec34-11e5-bbd6-91bbc2299c26---system---9aa06252-e9c6-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66---1
pojo_obj properties :-) parth---App_Welcome---4cc19690-e819-11e5-a3a1-c1cf090b354c---Analytics Team---ff81457a-e9cf-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66
pojo_obj properties :-) ravi---App_Welcome---d1515310-e9ad-11e5-b18e-c1cf090b354c---Analytics Team---ff81457a-e9cf-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66

16/04/04 11:50:42 ERROR DefaultErrorHandler: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.system.tableManager.TreeStructContainer.getOtherAccessContainer(TreeStructContainer.scala:245)
    at com.analytics.UI.views.ObjectLevelAccess$1.valueChange(ObjectLevelAccess.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1008)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.fireValueChange(AbstractField.java:1159)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.setValue(AbstractField.java:570)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractSelect.setValue(AbstractSelect.java:729)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField.setValue(AbstractField.java:468)
    at com.vaadin.ui.ComboBox.changeVariables(ComboBox.java:730)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.changeVariables(ServerRpcHandler.java:603)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:422)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:273)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:79)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1409)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some times Vaadin container **addItem** return null instead of new Item id.

So, better option to use `container.getItem(container.addItem)` instead of `container.addItem()`.

Or add you own custom item Id like `container.addItem(customId)` for eatch item you want to add in container.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, because `addItem()`  returns the same as `getItem()`. Although let me try it using bothsuggestions. I am considering this suggestion because in previous all Hierarchical container i explicitly added the ItemId in `addItem()`.

Comment: I am surprised that it's working..!! I think in my case, `addItem()` is returning null. But i can't figure out **"why..?"**